# How to receive data in rabbitmq when I run the frontend(website) in rabbitmq. Not Just 'Hello' but all the data like login, register, logout

Tags: python, rabbitmq, frontend

I dont't recieve the data when I run the frontend.

I have tried many scripts but I only recieve hello in rabbitmq. I don't reciece all the data when I run the frontend.

Comment: I don't think anyone will be able to help you, based on the information you have provided. Try to focus on one _specific_ problem and show us the relevant code for that problem. Why do you _expect_ to receive more data than you are actually receiving? What is "the front end" you are using? What do you mean by "many scripts"? How are you trying to use Rabbit?

Comment: You can also take a look at [mre] for guidance on how to do this - and more general guidance in the [help] and by reading [ask].