# How to get all data in rabbitmq when I run website(frontend)

Tags: python, rabbitmq, frontend

```py
import pika, sys, os
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(username='danny', password='123', erase_on_connect=True)
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(host='10.147.18.152', port=5672, virtual_host='490', credentials=credentials)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
from website import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

connection.close()
```

I have this code and I only get just "hello" in rabbitmq when I run the website. I do not get the all data in rabbitmq when I run the website.

Comment: Try https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-python.html

Comment: You can edit your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74662210/12567365) and add the extra details there, instead of creating a new, effectively duplicate, question.

Comment: But please also take another look at the guidance provided in the comments for that other question.